# Customize MDI in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mdi

In my project i have to run multi-interfaces at a time. I used isMdicontainer property. But problem is whole area is converted to MDI. Can i set boundaries for it,like in Photoshop(below menu-bar there is toolbar,below toolbar Mdi is appearing).

And I like the tab structure in Photoshop used to switch images. How can i introduce that into my project for switching between forms. I am using VS 2010, Doing project in C#(Win forms), net framework 3.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use container controls like Panels and Dock them to the side — this will reduce the area of the MDI child area.

As far as tabs are concerned, that's a different beast than the MDI model.  You can try [Multi Document Interface (MDI) tab page browsing with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12514/Multi-Document-Interface-MDI-tab-page-browsing-wit)

Comment: But in their code,there is a bug. If we make full screen a form,then other form will become hidden. That is switching becomes impossible.

Comment: @VishnuTS I never tried it.  If you really want the tab interface, then you would have to drop the MDI interface, and treat forms as just usercontrols (no border, dock = fill, .TopLevel = false, etc).  Then you just have to track tabs instead of forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things,

The following tasks are illustrated [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233676%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

- Creating the main menu for your form. The actual name of the menu
  will vary.
- Adding the ToolStripPanel control to the Toolbox.
- Creating a child form.
- Arranging ToolStripPanel controls by z-order.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should give you a start.

- Add a `MenuBar` a `ToolStrip` and a `TabControl` to your main form.
- Set their `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Top`.
- Resize the `TabControl` so that the tabpages are hidden.
- When you open a new MDI form add a tab and select it.